A connections style puzzle
In Connections, the goal is to find four groups of four words. The four words belong to some category.











Style
Insurance
Arrow
Messenger


Spike
Eggs
Line
Forlorn


Triangle
Birds
Taiwan
Freedom


Chevron
Toucan
Goose
Hack



Can you find what the categories are and which 4 words belong to each of the four categories?
Hint:


 The category containing "Birds" does not have much more than 4 items and the 4 here are for sure the most obvious ones.




 THINGS WITH SHARP EDGES: SPIKE ARROW CHEVRON TRIANGLE.


 SOMETHING YOU CAN ADD “LIFE” TO AS A PREFIX TO MAKE A PHRASE: LINE STYLE HACK INSURANCE


 HAS NUMBERS PHONETICALLY IN THEIR NAMES: taiWAN, FREEdom, FORlorn, TOUcan


 RELATED TO PIDGEONS???: BIRD GOOSE EGGS MESSENGER

